# I want to pursue a career in computer programming. Where do I start?

Tags: programming-languages

I am currently finishing up my junior year as a Biochemistry major at a 4-year university. In a year, I will graduate with a B.S. in Biochemistry and way more credit hours than anyone should ever have due to AP classes in high school. To make a long story short, I want to pursue computer programming once I graduate next year. I need to know what to do now, where I should go next. My university does not offer any CS classes, but I am willing to work extracurricularly if it means gaining relevant experience. I'm not completely at square 1, I have some experience with programming, but not nearly enough to compete with a Bachelor's.

1) **Do I need a Bachelor's in CS to pursue programming?** I have developed and published a handful of websites and iPhone/Android applications over the years, but I never took it on as a full time job. I am conversant in most relevant computer languages, but never as a result of any official classes, just through personal study.

2) **What resources are available to me regarding open positions in CS?** I have been stuck in my birth state my entire life, and thus have little exposure to the job market outside of a 200-mile radius. I am engaged and plan to move away with my fiancé when we both graduate next year, but I would like to move somewhere that will be conducive to my programming ambitions. Are there any notable cities that are iconic in the CS market?

3) **What should I be focusing on now?** I would like to finish out my degree program so the past 3 years won't be completely for naught, but what should I be doing in the meantime? Should I pursue some form of internship, should I attempt to strike further out in freelance work, or should I take some sort of online classes?

4) **What do employers look for?** If I'm looking to make the best first impression, what sort of things should I become conversant in? Is there a core set of languages I should go ahead and start learning?

Honestly I'm just extremely lost and need to know what steps I should take from here. Also, if I can avoid paying for another 4 years of college, that would be great.

Comment: Unfortunately career advice is off-topic here, as it is fundamentally subjective, and what's right for each person is different.  See our [help/dont-ask].  Also, your question seems to be about programming, and this site is not a place for programming questions.  Our focus is on answerable, technical questions about computer *science*.

Comment: Move to the Bay Area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are *already* making iOS Apps, so you most likely *already* know at least 1 programming language. You **don't need a degree in computer science to be a programmer**. You (usually) need a degree in computer science to be a computer *scientist*.

You should continue programming, as **it's the only way you'll get better**. If you want to put it on your resume you need to be extremely fluent in at least 1 language and *show* that you're fluent (you're off to a great start with those iOS apps).

Employers don't look for a CS degree, although it is nice. Most jobs require a bachelors degree, but not *in* computer science per se.

Putting personal projects on your resume along with an explanation of your ability to write code should be good enough. And trust me, they will be testing your abilities as a programmer from the second you get a callback.

During the first interview, you will most likely be asked to write code on paper with a developer at the company. If you pass that, they might ask you to complete a [lengthy exercise](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/63259/asked-to-complete-interview-exercise-but-ignoring-github-work-demoing-expertise/63263#63263) to demonstrate your proficiency.

So in my opinion: **Keep doing what you're doing**. If you want to land a job as a programmer master at least 1 language.

Comment: Thank you for the help, that's tremendously encouraging as I've had little to no luck finding job postings that don't require a BS in Computer Science. I'll keep looking and try to find a language or two to master.